# Getting a IllegalArgumentException for Random.nextint in Google Play's crash report

Tags: android

I was looking at my crash report and it says the following report

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
in java.util.Random.nextInt

I do not understand this, nextint takes only a int of the max random number to return, and java compiler will not allow you to put in a different type.

How could this exception be going off?????

Comment: Please post the stacktrace

Comment: Now if only Java supported `uint`s, this would not be possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in doubt, you can always grep the JDK. In this instance, you can look up Random.nextInt [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Random.java#Random.nextInt%28%29). Looking at the source code, `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown if and only if the given integer is not positive.

For the sake of completeness, the relevant code reads:

```
public int nextInt(int n) {
   if (n <= 0)
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");

   if ((n & -n) == n)  // i.e., n is a power of 2
     return (int)((n * (long)next(31)) >> 31);

   int bits, val;
   do {
       bits = next(31);
       val = bits % n;
    while (bits - val + (n-1) < 0);
   return val;
 }}
```

Edit: The OP asked a question in the comments,

> could you explain "grep the JDK"?

Here I mean a search on [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/) for "Random.nextInt".

Comment: Hi Thank you for the comment, could you explain " grep the JDK"

Answer (score 0):

Nextint throws IllegalArgumentException only when the value given is non-positive.

Comment: I think this is almost but not quite correct. The `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown if and only if the given integer is not positive (which includes the case 0, a non-negative integer). I've referenced docs+code in my answer in case this helps to clarify this.